# Spyder not opening from Anaconda anymore

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

After still working on a Python script in Spyder the evening before, Spyder stopped opening from the Anaconda Navigator menu the next morning.

Following the described troubleshooting of first resetting all Spyder settings and later reinstalling Anaconda as described did unfortunately not solve the problem for me.

The error message I get is the following (Windows account name masked):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3718, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3559, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 955, in setup
    self.editor = Editor(self)
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\plugin.py", line 178, in __init__
    self.autosave.try_recover_from_autosave()
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\utils\autosave.py", line 176, in try_recover_from_autosave
    files_to_recover, pidfiles = self.get_files_to_recover()
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\utils\autosave.py", line 149, in get_files_to_recover
    txt_as_dict = ast.literal_eval(txt)
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Installed package versions:

```
$ conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\<my account name>\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
[...]
anaconda                  2020.02                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0
[...]
spyder                    4.0.1                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            1.8.1                    py37_0
[...]
```

Additional remarks: I run Anaconda/Spyder on a Windows 10 laptop.

Thank you all very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This was a problem with our [autosave mechanism](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11375) and it's fixed in our **4.1.1** version, released on March 19th 2020.